# Failed to get wcf data member value

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I am trying to add a data member to wcf application but failed to get its value. I created a DataContract class in my service and set the value to an object of this DataContract class in my console application. However, I failed to get the value I assigned. Here are the service codes.

```
namespace WcfServices
{   
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICDNManagementService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SetBlobInformation")]
        void SetBlobInformation(BlobInformation blobInformation);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetBlobInformation")]
        BlobInformation GetBlobInformation();
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class BlobInformation
    {
        string _azureBlobUrl;

        [DataMember]
        public string azureBlobUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return _azureBlobUrl;
            }
            set
            {
                _azureBlobUrl = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace WcfServices
{
    public class CDNManagementService : ICDNManagementService
    {
        BlobInformation blobInformation = new BlobInformation();

        public void SetBlobInformation(BlobInformation blobinformation)
        {
            Logger.Log("azureBlobUrl= " + blobinformation.azureBlobUrl);
            Logger.Log("Before SetBlobInformation: " + blobInformation.azureBlobUrl);
            blobInformation = blobinformation;
            Logger.Log("After SetBlobInformation: " + blobInformation.azureBlobUrl);

        }

        public BlobInformation GetBlobInformation()
        {
            Logger.Log("In GetBlobInformation: " + blobInformation.azureBlobUrl);
            return blobInformation;            

        }
    }
}
```

My client side code are as follows.

```
namespace StringParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string blobUrl = "MyBlobUrl";

            CDNManagementService objCDNManagementService = new CDNManagementService();

            BlobInformation objBlobInformation = new BlobInformation();
            objBlobInformation.azureBlobUrl = blobUrl;
            objCDNManagementService.SetBlobInformation(objBlobInformation);

            BlobInformation tmpBlobInformation = new BlobInformation();

            tmpBlobInformation = objCDNManagementService.GetBlobInformation();
            Console.WriteLine(tmpBlobInformation.azureBlobUrl);

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        }

     }
}
```

The console output:

```
Hello World
```

And the messages I logged are:

```
azureBlobUrl= MyBlobUrl

Before SetBlobInformation:

After SetBlobInformation: MyBlobUrl

In GetBlobInformation:
```

Why didn't I get "MyBlobUrl" in console output and "In GetBlobInformation: MyBlobUrl" in my log? Did I do something wrong here or miss something? Any help is appreciated.

Update:

I added a constructor to the service:

```
public class CDNManagementService : ICDNManagementService
{
    BlobInformation _blobInformation = new BlobInformation();

    public CDNManagementService()
    {
        _blobInformation.azureBlobUrl = "DefaultUrl";
    }
    ......
}
```

Client code:

```
    string blobUrl = "MyBlobUrl";

    CDNManagementService objCDNManagementService = new CDNManagementService();
    BlobInformation objBlobInformation = new BlobInformation();

    objBlobInformation = objCDNManagementService.GetBlobInformation();
    Console.WriteLine(objBlobInformation.azureBlobUrl);

    objBlobInformation.azureBlobUrl = blobUrl;
    objCDNManagementService.SetBlobInformation(objBlobInformation);

    BlobInformation tmpBlobInformation = new BlobInformation();
    tmpBlobInformation = objCDNManagementService.GetBlobInformation();
    Console.WriteLine(tmpBlobInformation.azureBlobUrl);
```

Console outputs:

```
DefaultUrl
DefaultUrl
Hello World
```

The messages logged:

```
In GetBlobInformation: DefaultUrl
azureBlobUrl= MyBlobUrl
Before SetBlobInformation: DefaultUrl
After SetBlobInformation: MyBlobUrl
In GetBlobInformation: DefaultUrl
```

It seems that the constructor was invoked before each OperationContract invoking. Does anybody know what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: because you're hiding the variable, if these are your actual names. rename `CDNManagementService.blobinformation` to `CDNManagementService._blobinformation`.

Comment: @ DrewJordan, I renamed CDNManagementService.blobInformation to CDNManagementService._blobInformation and changed 'public void SetBlobInformation(BlobInformation blobinformation)' to 'public void SetBlobInformation(BlobInformation blobInformation)'. I got the same outputs and logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CDNManagementService` should look like this:

```
namespace WcfServices
{
    public class CDNManagementService : ICDNManagementService
    {
        BlobInformation _blobInformation = new BlobInformation();

        public void SetBlobInformation(BlobInformation blobinformation)
        {
            Logger.Log("azureBlobUrl= " + blobinformation.azureBlobUrl);
            Logger.Log("Before SetBlobInformation: " + _blobInformation.azureBlobUrl);
            _blobInformation = blobinformation;
            Logger.Log("After SetBlobInformation: " + _blobInformation.azureBlobUrl);

        }

        public BlobInformation GetBlobInformation()
        {
            Logger.Log("In GetBlobInformation: " + _blobInformation.azureBlobUrl);
            return _blobInformation;            

        }
    }
}
```

The way you wrote it:

> ```
>     public void SetBlobInformation(BlobInformation blobinformation)
>     {
>         Logger.Log("azureBlobUrl= " + blobinformation.azureBlobUrl);
>         Logger.Log("Before SetBlobInformation: " + blobInformation.azureBlobUrl);
>         blobInformation = blobinformation;
>         Logger.Log("After SetBlobInformation: " + blobInformation.azureBlobUrl);
>
>     }
> ```

The compiler couldn't tell the difference between what you were trying to set and the parameter you passed in, since they had the same name. You also would only log information from the parameter. When there are two variables with the same exact name, the one closest to the current scope (poor wording, I know) is preferred. This means that in your method, it would always try to use the parameter value first. This works even in the assignment statement: it will see the left side first, and try to assign the class field to the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. After your first comment, I made modifications to my code and it looks the same as yours in your answer. I updated Web Reference and got the same results. Not quite sure what happened here.